# jquery ui dynamic table onclick event is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-click-event, tablesorter

I have requirement to display  dynamic table in jquery. On clicking on table data  the value should set in below text field.

May I know how to capture the name from dynamic table and set into text field

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Retrieve the JSON data from the server using AJAX
    $('#AJAXButton').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('ajax/ajaxtest.js', function(data) {
            processJSON(data);
        });
    });

    //Process and display the JSON data
    function processJSON(data) {
        var output = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Platform</th></tr>';
        //Loop through the Languages 
        $(data.Languages).each(function(index, element) {
            output += '<tr><td class="clickable">' + element.Name + '</td>' + 
              '<td class="clickable">' + element.Platform + '</td></tr>';
        });
        output += '</table>';
        $('#AJAXDiv').html(output);
    }

    $("tr.clickable").live("click", function() {
            $("#name").append(?);
    });

});


<div id="AJAXDiv" style="width:400px; height:600px; background-color:#ddd; border:1px solid black">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="name">Created by: </label> <input id="name" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wXpzr/2/) fiddle and let me know if it's not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the event to happen when the row is clicked, so you just put the 'clickable' class on your row instead of every 'td'. The click handler can then access first 'td' within that row (the name that you are after).

ie. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wTxLz/2/)

Comment: No problem! Please mark as answer if this is what you were after! =)